Epoxy grout, micro cement or shower pan over failed grout?
New construction bathroom 2 years ago. Hired a tiler to install herringbone pattern tiles on the floor and large format tiles for the walls. I noticed while rinsing the shower after cleaning it that there was sand everywhere. Long story short, it's impossible to keep clean as yuck collects where grout once was and I need a solution to repair this and make it hygienic for my sanity. Since a significant portion of the grout is now gone can I use epoxy grout over this? I would do a very intensive deep clean 1st and let it dry out for some time. The other option I am researching is microcement over the tiles and grout. But my preferred option is to install a 1 piece shower pan and cover it but that would require the bottom row of our large format tiles to be removed so we could tile over the lip of the shower pan. Anyone have any ideas or thoughts to help? My husband is just ignoring it so I'm on my own.

What do you mean the grout is gone? Can you take a photo?

Sounds like the wrong grout was used.  A picture will help greatly.  Without knowing more it is feasible to use epoxy grout if all the old grout is cleaned out.  However again you want the correct grout for the tile and grout line size.  If you have stone tile it will need to be sealed as well.
